# Laravel Cashier - Stripe - set preferred locale to a customer

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I want to create a customer (or edit a existing one) adding a preferred_locales value.

Is there a way to do it directly with Laravel Cashier? If not, what would be the best workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler and more up to date way to do it

```
$user->updateStripeCustomer(['preferred_locales' => ['es']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done, for a case someone needs it in the future

```
        $c = $user->createAsStripeCustomer();

        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(\Config::get('values.stripe_secret'));

        \Stripe\Customer::update(
            $c->id,
            [
                'preferred_locales' => ['es'],
            ]
        );
```